# CRLF translation with Unicode in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I'm trying to write to a Unicode (UCS-2 Little Endian) file in Perl on Windows, like this.

```
open my $f, ">$fName" or die "can't write $fName\n";
binmode $f, ':raw:encoding(UCS-2LE)';
print $f, "ohai\ni can haz unicodez?\nkthxbye\n";
close $f;
```

It basically works except I no longer get the automatic LF -> CR/LF translation on output that I get on regular text files.  (The output files just have LF)  If I leave out :raw or add :crlf in the "binmode" call, then the output file is garbled.  I've tried re-ordering the "directives" (i.e. :encoding before :raw) and can't get it to work.  The same problem exists for reading.

Answer (score 2):

The `:crlf` layer does a simple byte mapping of 0x0A -> 0x0D 0x0A (`\n --> \r\n`) in the output stream, but for the most part this isn't valid in any wide character encoding.

How about using a raw mode but explicitly print the CR?

```
print $f "ohai\r\ni can haz unicodez?\r\nkthxbye\r\n";
```

Or if portability is a concern, discover and explicitly use the correct line ending:

```
## never mind - $/ doesn't work
# print $f "ohai$/i can haz unicodez?$/kthxbye$/";

open DUMMY, '>', 'dummy'; print DUMMY "\n"; close DUMMY;
open DUMMY, '<:raw', 'dummy'; $EOL = <DUMMY>; close DUMMY;
unlink 'dummy';

...

print $f "ohai${EOL}i can haz unicodez?${EOL}kthxbye${EOL}";
```

---

Unrelated to the question, but Ωmega
asked in a comment about the difference between `:raw` and `:bytes`. As documented in `perldoc perlio`, you can think of `:raw` as removing all I/O layers, and `:bytes` as removing a `:utf8` layer. Compare the output of these two commands:

```
$ perl -E 'binmode *STDOUT,":crlf:raw"; say' | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001


$ perl -E 'binmode *STDOUT,":crlf:bytes";say' | od -c
0000000  \r  \n
0000002
```

Comment: There's no way to make the :crlf layer work before the :encoding layer?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Maybe somebody else has an idea.

Comment: Could you please clarify a difference between `:raw` and `:bytes`?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on windows:

```
open my $f, ">:encoding(UCS-2LE):crlf", "test.txt";
print $f "ohai\ni can haz unicodez?\nkthxbye\n";
close $f;
```

Yielding UCS-16 LE output in test.txt of

```
ohai
i can haz unicodez?
kthxbye
```

Comment: Really?! The 2nd line looks like Asian characters when I open that in Notepad+ (which has Unicode support).  And when I open it in HexEdit, I can see why... the lines end in \x00 \x0D \x0A (instead of \x00 \x0D \x00 \x0A) which makes the second line "out of sync"

Comment: I see the line ending in \x00 \x0D \x00 \x0A.  or as hexlify-buffer puts it, `0d00 0a00`.  What version of perl are you using?  I'm using the latest strawberry distribution.

Comment: Wow, this is weird... I am also using the latest Strawberry Perl (5.12), and I just tried it again to make sure... I am still seeing 00 0D 0A... Maybe you are using 5.10 and this is a bug introduced in 5.12?

Comment: `This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 0 (v5.12.0) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread`, not that this helps us much.  I wonder if I have some sort of module installed that's affecting encoding and crlf.  I'll try from another computer or two when I have access and post results.

Comment: Maybe the OS matters?  I am on Windows 7 64-bit (although I am using MSWin32-x86-multi-thread same as you)

Comment: Mysterious - I can repro your problem on another 32 bit XP machine with the same perl version.  I am at a loss as to what is going on, but it doesn't look like this works in general.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have found to work, at least with perl 5.10.1:

Input:

```
open(my $f_in, '<:raw:perlio:via(File::BOM):crlf', $file);
```

Output:

```
open(my $f_out, '>:raw:perlio:encoding(UTF-16LE):crlf:via(File::BOM)', $file);
```

These handle BOM, CRLF translation, and UTF-16LE encoding/decoding transparently.

Note that according to the perlmonks post below, if trying to specify with binmode() instead of open(), an extra ":pop" is required:

```
binmode $f_out, ':raw:pop:perlio:encoding(UTF-16LE):crlf';
```

which my experience corroborates.  I was not able to get this to work with the ":via(File::BOM)" layer, however.

References:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=608532

[http://metacpan.org/pod/File::BOM](http://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aBOM)

Answer (score 0):

So the implicit question seems to be: How the heck is this IO layer business supposed to be used properly? Or perhaps: Is there a bug in the implementation of the `:crlf` layer?

After 13 years, there is no clarity. But the short answer is that `:crlf` seems to be meant to be applied – somewhat counter-intuitively – **after** any `:encoding(…)` layer and not before as doing otherwise will result in garbled output for UTF-16/UCS-2 as can be demonstrated using Perl 5.36.0 MSYS on Windows (shipping with "Git for Windows"), which by the way does **not** have `:crlf` enabled by default:

```
$ perl -E "say for PerlIO::get_layers(*STDOUT)"
unix
perlio
$ perl -Mopen=":std,OUT,:encoding(UCS-2LE):crlf" -E say | od -c
0000000  \r  \0  \n  \0   → correct

$ perl -Mopen=":std,OUT,:crlf:encoding(UCS-2LE)" -E say | od -c
0000000  \r  \n  \0       → wrong!
```

The [PerlIO doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO) says:

> On DOS/Windows like architectures where this layer is part of the defaults, it also acts like the :perlio layer, and removing the CRLF translation (such as with :raw) will only unset the CRLF translation flag.

Talk of a "translation flag" *seems* to suggest that it is another so-called pseudo-layer which sets a flag respected by other layers, but I don't know whether that is actually the case.

> Since Perl 5.14, you can also apply another :crlf layer later, such as when the CRLF translation must occur after an encoding layer.

The very notion that CRLF translation should occur after encoding seems counter-intuitive in the case of UTF-16/UCS-2.

All this seems a bit quirky and not properly specified. To add to the confusion (or possibly gain more insight), read the [`open::layers` doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/open::layers), where it seems someone with more knowledge than me has studied the issue and made a list of "historical quirks" and "issues".

This is as far as my own research has brought me and I'll leave it there.